# Ember.js controller destroyed function

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In `Ember.js` on an `ObjectController` there is a function `init()` which fires when the controller is instantiated. Is there a way I can fire some additional code, when the controller leaves context?

Here is what I am doing in the `init()`:

```
init: function() {
    jQuery("body").css("background-color", "#f2f1ec");
}
```

On the controller exit, or lose context I want to simply change the background color again:

```
jQuery("body").css("background-color", "#333333");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to set a background color an `Ember.View`s `didInsertElement` hook?

Comment: @MehulKar I think you are spot on here, can you maybe provide a small example of how that looks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a custom view and write make the css changes on `didInsertElement` instead of handling it in the controller. In this particular case, since you're operating on the `body` element, you might even be able to get away with doing it in the `activate` and `deactivate` functions of the route you're looking to target. (It might be a problem if you're doing it on `ApplicationRoute` though. Not sure if that is entered before are after `document.ready()`

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8YbSA/) using the Router's `activate` and `deactivate` functions.

And here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/4AJfj/) of the custom view.

Comment: Awesome, went with `didInsertElement` and `willDestroyElement`. Works perfectly.